# How to delete the cache files when the file cache module is installed

Tags: caching

You have a site with the filecache module that saves the cache in files instead of the database.

The filecache directory to date has a size of 30 Gigabytes. You want to disable the module filecache and tell the Drupal system to save the cache in its corresponding database tables. Does anyone know how to do these two processes?

Thank you for your cooperation

Comment: How does the site fail?

Comment: when you open the browser and place the site address simply do not load